# very strange behavior with UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a simple tableView where the value in `numberOfRowsInSection` depends on the type of data I am displaying, ie, names or details, etc..

The table is first loaded with certain details where the row count is 6. I added an `NSLog` statement and indeed I am returning 6 rows.

I also have to set the row height and again, my log statements says it is being called 6 times. great. My problem is `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is only called 5 times. it's missing the last call.

Note: I have a toolBar that reloads the table with different options. When I select a new option then go back, the table populates properly. It has 6 rows as it should have.
Everything is connected properly: delegate, datasource and outlet as proven by the fact that the table is being partially loaded. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening or how to  fix it?

Comment: Some code would be helpful ;)

Comment: Is the last cell possibly not visible? `cellForRowAtIndexPath` won't be called for a cell that is not visible.

Comment: This was the problem. I need to set the frame according to screen size because one display type has buttons and my table moves accordingly. I tried to make the frame matched the XIB but for some reason that wasn't working. Thanks for your answer. You saved me. I think you answered first, would love to give you the prize :)

Answer (score 2):

If your last cell is not visible on the screen the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` won't be called if you don't scroll and make the cell visible.